# Custom lightning component disappears without errors in log, when button clicked, but only in production

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, change-set

I have the same lightning-button-stateful onclick event handler in the sandbox and in production.

```
_handleSectionExpandCollapse(event) {
let content = event.target.parentElement;
event.target.selected = !event.target.selected;

content
  .getElementsByClassName("hiddenWhenCollapsed")
  .forEach(function(item) {
    item.classList.toggle("hidden");
  });

if (content.style.maxHeight) {
  content.style.maxHeight = null;
  content.getElementsByClassName("cnt_right")[0].style.maxHeight = null;
  content.getElementsByClassName("cnt_right")[0].style.overflowY = "hidden";
  content.getElementsByClassName("vlContainer")[0].style.height = 0;
} else {
  const expandedHeight = this.isAccountsRow
    ? "200px"
    : content.scrollHeight - 30 + "px";

  content.style.maxHeight = "inherit";
  content.getElementsByClassName(
    "cnt_right"
  )[0].style.maxHeight = expandedHeight;
  content.getElementsByClassName("cnt_right")[0].style.overflowY = "scroll";
  content.getElementsByClassName(
    "vlContainer"
  )[0].style.height = expandedHeight;
}
```

}

In the sandbox, it works perfectly. In production, it doesn't (my custom lightning component just disappears when I click this button, without any errors in browser log).

Production was built from changeset created in the sandbox. All dependencies were added to the changeset.

Maybe someone knows what's wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix.
Lightning and Aura components use Secure Wrappers, so we are not able to use features like getElementsByClassName or getElementById. See more: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.security_locker_global_access

But instead should be used query selectors on shadow DOM:

```
this.template.querySelectorAll('.hiddenWhenCollapsed'); 
this.template.querySelector(".cnt_right").style.maxHeight = null;
```